# How do you save texture as an image to disk with python

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, scripting

Okay, I got a working example that I was able to assemble, by setting the image settings I was able to get a smaller array size to disk with a smaller image. So I saved an image to disk, loaded it back then converted it to a numpy form of array and saved the array to disk to use as data for characters in a game. Each time the characters need information they use the data array. At least this is my intended plan for later for characters to be able to use data from array

I was reading that with textures the operation is much faster and costs even less disk space.
For me saving to disk is necessary because I want to create a game library for characters to use from the disk. Saving a texture to disk in a form of an image is less costly on resources and faster.

Working setup that I'm not happy with.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import sys
import numpy as np
import bge
import imbuf
#Defining contextual objects from the scene I want.
scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.scene.objects["Camera_1"]


# render settings to make image smaller and less costly and render to disk image.
scene.render.resolution_x = 64
scene.render.resolution_y = 32
scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
scene.render.filepath = "/Users/me/Downloads/temp/a.JPEG"
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = 1)


#Load image  to disk to work with
# Edited out by me - imbuf.load("/Users/me/Downloads/temp/a.JPEG") not working. Using bpy data instead.
bpy_img = bpy.data.images.load("/Users/me/Downloads/temp/a.JPEG")

#removed imbuf and added bpy_img variable.
arr = np.array(bpy_img.pixels[:])

#Checking array is there
print (arr)

#save array to disk.
fname2 = "/Users/me/Downloads/temp/depth.npz" 
with open(fname2, "wb") as f:
    np.savez(f, arr)

#code is working now, it was givign atribute error due to imbuf
```

So I found a way to take an image from camera view at the click of the "start game engine" by using the `bpy.ops.render.render` The camera records what is in it's view, takes picture. I did this by nesting variables "variable=bpy.context.scene.objects["Camera_1"]"

When I call the variable to render  it renders the camera directly by using "scene.render"+camera and then giving the `bpy.ops.render.render`

But I want to do it with a texture, without saving the whole image buffer of an image from the camera view. Meaning I want to save just the texture to disk as an image, it should appear like something diffused with loose edges, because it's without vertexes.

I sort of want to go this way avoid Bpy

```
import bge

contr = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
obj = contr.owner

camera = scene.objects['Camera_1']
texture = bge.texture.ImageRender(scene,camera)

imageArray = bge.texture.imageToArray(texture, 'RGB')
charArray = imageArray.to_list()
print(charArray)
```

Okay now what, I'm getting some numeric data from the array in my console, how do I save the texture as an image to disk, only the texture. How do I continue this code and export the texture to disk as an image, jpg, png whatever.

Make Screenshot does not work, there is no way for me to connect the variables to it.
I sort of wanted to mix these two code sniplets and make one out of them.

MakeScreenshot does not work, it just takes a screen shot of the whole scene, or at least I don't know how to use it ? is it any other way, I don't think make screenshot take a snap of just the texture.

So making a smaller image by just taking an image of the texture makes the numpy array even smaller and faster to load.

Can I mix Bge and Bpy modules, Bge module deals with textures, and bpy can render an image to disk.

These are not used yet
`contr = bge.logic.getCurrentController() and obj = contr.owner`

They define the camera from the logic editor perspective.
I plan to use them later if I need, the data comes from the scene that I'm getting. If it does not work by me getting the data from the ."get current scene", maybe I can get it from the logic controller. It does give out data just that I don't know how to render the texture with "scene" variable to disk.

## =====================================<

Okay I edited my code it looks like this now.

```
#import all stuf I may need later
import bpy
import mathutils
import sys
import numpy as np
import bge
import imbuf


#Defining contextual objects from the scene I want.
scene = bpy.context.scene
#For use when I want to save or use data from buffer 
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.scene.objects["Camera_1"]



# indices start from 0
# pixel location is a list of 2 elements -> [x,y]
# and the [0,0] is the left bottom corner
# color is a list of 4 elements -> [r,g,b,a]
def set_pixel_color(image,pixel_location,color):
    size_x = image.size[0]
    r = pixel_location[1] * size_x * 4 + pixel_location[0] * 4
    g = r + 1
    b = r + 2
    a = r + 3
    for i,index in enumerate((r,g,b,a)):
        image.pixels[index] = color[i]


#Loaded image, no need for old and new :) has all the chanels, dumb me
#$One of the two loaded or blank
image_new = bpy.data.images.load("/Users/me/Downloads/temp/a.JPEG")
#image_new = bpy.data.images.new(name = 'newimage',width=800,height=600,alpha=True)
color = [0,1,0,1]
pixel_location = [15,15]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)

color = [1,0,0,1]
pixel_location = [0,0]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)

mypath = '/Users/me/Downloads/temp/new_modified_A.PNG'
image_new.filepath = mypath
image_new.save()
```

thank you for your help and answers  MohammadHossein Jamshidi
But ....
Regarding when I use the blank format to create new image with python or loading one of my images from file.
I was expecting in the blank image some pixels but the image is just dark, no pixels there as a dot in a black image. It does save the image, but I was expecting the image to be modified from blank to a blank with a dot on it.
When I create a blank new image it does not have any pixel on it, it's just dark color without anything, for example pixel_location = [15,15] should of produced a pixel there in that spot, but it's not there. You have any idea what is causing pixel not to show up ? Even the images that I load turn dark and they re just blank,maybe there is a problem in your code ?

**== Latest edit by me == **

**found the problem**

Is this with pil ?
Maybe it's why it does not work, pil may not work with BGE only with blender animation ?
This looks like pil function.

```
#mypath = '/Users/me/Downloads/temp/new.PNG'
#image_new.filepath = mypath
#image_new.save()
```

I quoted everything out and added
image_new = bpy.data.images["FFAAEM.jpg"]
I forced the image of the texture directly, if I leave the save function it generates a black screen on the plane where the texture projects.
I have a plane where the texture is projected, the texture image is: (a map of Europe)

Instead of : image_new = bpy.data.images["0"]

I forced the image to: image_new = bpy.data.images["FFAAEM.jpg"]

FFAAEM.jpg is the texture of the image, the image that I have applied on the plane. I connected a camera to the logical editor with always sensor function and python controller connected with the sensor and hooked it up to the script to get an image of the plane/wall.

Results are:
if I cut the save function from the script the projected plane no longer is dark in camera view, texture is shown when I start game engine but I can't save.

I put the save function on the plane where the texture should be showing the world map go's pitch black and so does the saved image that is saved by this save function you gave me. So not only does the saved image is dark but also the image on the wall where the texture is instantly turns black in the game engine, Remove save function the map comes back with europe.

So it's the save function, I remove it the plane stays with the texture on and the map is shown on the plane (wall) the plane is made out to be a wall.
I put the save function on and run the game engine the plane/wall turns pitch black and so does the image it saves. So this is the problem, the save function cancels the results for some reason and turns everything pitch black. I get a black wall projected onto the plane.

It's the save function, I think it over rides the results.
This is the code with disabled save function things project on the wall and I get map of europe. I will try to upload a blend file maybe with everthing texture, script.

```
import bpy
import bge
import PIL
from PIL import Image
#Defining contextual objects from the scene I want.
scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.context.scene.objects["Camera.002"]

image_new = bpy.data.images["FFAAEM.jpg"]

# indices start from 0
# pixel location is a list of 2 elements -> [x,y]
# and the [0,0] is the left bottom corner
# color is a list of 4 elements -> [r,g,b,a]
def set_pixel_color(image,pixel_location,color):
    size_x = image.size[0]
    r = pixel_location[1] * size_x * 4 + pixel_location[0] * 4
    g = r + 1
    b = r + 2
    a = r + 3
    for i,index in enumerate((r,g,b,a)):
        image.pixels[index] = color[i]
color = [0,1,0,1]
pixel_location = [15,15]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)
color = [1,0,0,1]
pixel_location = [0,0]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)
#mypath = '/Users/me/Downloads/temp/new.PNG'
#image_new.filepath = mypath
#image_new.save()
```

I put the save function on run game engine everything turns black on the wall.
It's the save function.

I have a camera named Camera.002 I defined it in the logical editor with sensor and py controler hooked up to the script. The view from the camera live turns the wall black when I add the save function, remove it like I have said the image comes back on the wall. So not only the image saved turns like that but also instantly in the game it turns black, the plane where the texture is added with material turns black.

I think I have gone far enough to get help and ended up with negative votes from the Kitties. {(^_^)} no offences taken I'm not here to collect fame.
People are very jumpy on this forum.

Finally I got it to spit out an error after I loaded an image  and put the image name [like this]

Error Image thepictureiloaded.png has no data.

clearly this save function overrides the buffer and invalidates it, just my opinion.  I don't see any render function in the script provided here, so my guess is that this function renders the image and invalidates it with with it's own refresh   Remove the save function, no more error.

Comment: Did you try `PIL` module?  `Image.save()`?

Comment: You have to install pil, it's not in blender by default ? I will have to look into installing the module.

Comment: It's not shipped with Blender install, you can check available packages using `help('modules')` on Python Interactive console. And I get a quick glance, didn't find out any "handy" image saving library there

Comment: I sort of fixed it, I left just the bpy.....render.render and removed all the file format and settings and path.   Now it saves the image to C:\temp  I cannot set a path for it, it won't let me, gives errors that scene.render is not a valid contex meaning I can't merge bpy with bge modules. Funny enough if I just leave bpy.ops.render.render it will render the texture to image. but it won't let me set anything, like image size, path and so on, saves it to the default temp folder as .png without a filename in front.

Comment: I looked at the image in C:\ temp folder and I am not pleased, I guess I will look into istalling pil, it does not look like it saved just the texture, it did render thru the camera view tho.

Comment: Okay I installed pil, tried import pil and it works, can you give an example on how I can save image from rendered texture or from array. I guess I have two options, save after the texture is rendered and convert to image with pil ? or from image array and convert there to image ? there is no image file, I have to define an image and write texture on it ? how do I do that

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use bpy functions. you should set image's `filepath` and just `save` like below:

```
import bpy

# create new image or just find your image in bpy.data
image_new = bpy.data.images.new(name = 'newimage',width=1024,height=1024,alpha=True)
image_old = bpy.data.images[0]

# saving image_new which is created above
mypath = 'D:/01 Projects/mytexture.png'
image_new.filepath = mypath
image_new.save()

# and you can save loaded images without setting filepath attribute:
image_old.save_render(filepath='D:/01 Projects/mytexture.png')
```

and you can access image data using `pixels` property. pixel count is 4x the number of pixels which means that each one of them is a channel of cell's color.
use the following function for modifying color data:

```
import bpy

# indices start from 0
# pixel location is a list of 2 elements -> [x,y]
# and the [0,0] is the left bottom corner
# color is a list of 4 elements -> [r,g,b,a]
def set_pixel_color(image,pixel_location,color):
    size_x = image.size[0]
    r = pixel_location[1] * size_x * 4 + pixel_location[0] * 4
    g = r + 1
    b = r + 2
    a = r + 3
    for i,index in enumerate((r,g,b,a)):
        image.pixels[index] = color[i]
```

check the above code with example below:

```
image_new = bpy.data.images.new(name = 'newimage',width=16,height=16,alpha=True)
color = [0,1,0,1]
pixel_location = [15,15]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)

color = [1,0,0,1]
pixel_location = [0,0]
set_pixel_color(image_new,pixel_location,color)
```

now find the created image in the `UV editor` and see the result

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116628/discussion-on-answer-by-mohammadhossein-jamshidi-how-do-you-save-texture-as-an-i).

Comment: Robert this guy is gone and I have zero answers :) thanks man I spent 1 week trying to find this all over the internet

Comment: @user104998 You can still contact him in the chatroom. The comment section just isn't meant for a long discussion. Also you can't reasonably expect that another user will reply within just a few hours, they may be busy with other things.

Comment: @user104998 As Robert already stated you can still contact the user in the chat linked in the first comment. The comments section is not for extended discussions and should be keep clean and minimal

Comment: It's fine, it does not work in UPBGE alpha3 the pil save function, and the script gives out of index for some reason on every single image I give it, or no data loaded when I add the pil save function. I had to go all the way to the developers of Upbge and find out that because it's alpha it has problems with pil and the other stuff of this script I guess . I don't want to go lower than alpha3, it has evee inetegrated and bpy that now works with the Bge game engine. But it has bugs